# Operating System not found, win7 dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, live-usb

After installing 14.04 from a liveUSB alongside windows 7 and encountering no problems for about a week, I shut down windows and rebooted only to see the "Operating system not found" message and being unable to boot into either.

Tried to boot to liveUSB again to try to run  boot repair, and now the liveUSB no longer boots either. I can get to the Ubuntu advanced boot options screen and run memtest86, but when I choose "try ubuntu" the screen hangs on the 14.04 loading screen with the orange dots. I've tried the f6 options (acpi off, noapic, nomodeset)

Any ideas? I'm writing this on an ipad (ugh) because I am now computer-less.

(Sony vaio laptop, Intel i7, nvidia card, running win7 and ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Update: win7 recover disk also hangs on "starting windows" screen

Comment: Did you Reset the BIOS? -> [Error: Operating system not found or missing operating system.](https://us.en.kb.sony.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/30721/~/error%3A-operating-system-not-found-or-missing-operating-system.)

Comment: Yeah, I've tried resetting the BIOS. I can't figure out why it won't boot from any devices.

Comment: Was the HDD detected in the BIOS?

Comment: Yeah, HDD detected.

Comment: Hmm the Sony Community is full of topics with this error perhaps you will find a solution there http://community.sony.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?filter=labels&q=operation+system+not+found

Comment: I've spent the past few days combing through the threads to no avail before I broke down and posted here, but I appreciate your comments! The issue w not booting to a live cd is what's puzzling and what I can't find info on, besides the obvious possibility of BIOS not recognizing devices.

Comment: Perhaps you should try to boot from a DVD after you removed the HDD out of the laptop (**don't forgett to remove the battery before open a laptop!**). There is also another curios solution -> http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f108/solved-vaio-operating-system-not-found-642806-3.html#post3729583 but it sounds dangerous...